# php bind_param for multiple values

Tags: php, mysqli

For some reason, when I try to use multiple bind params I can't get them to work.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `course_timetable` WHERE 'student_id'=(SELECT 'student_id' FROM `student_accounts` WHERE `username`=?) AND `group`= (SELECT `group` FROM `student_timetable` WHERE `student_id` = (SELECT `student_id` FROM `student_accounts` WHERE `username`=?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $inputUser, $inputUser);
```

This is the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in
>   /home/u926308913/public_html/get_user_timetable.php on line 10

Comment: You have an error in you SQL syntax. 'student_id' should be \`student_id\` (backquotes). Maybe, some other errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$mysqli->prepare` function is most likely returning false, due to an error in your SQL statement.

I do notice the following errors:

```
SELECT * FROM `course_timetable` WHERE 'student_id'=(SELECT 'student_id' FROM `student_accounts` WHERE `username`=?) AND `group`= (SELECT `group` FROM `student_timetable` WHERE `student_id` = (SELECT `student_id` FROM `student_accounts` WHERE `username`=?)
---------------------------------------^----------^---------^----------^
```

Try replacing ' with `

Before binding the parameters, you can make sure the prepare statement succeeded, by doing this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `course_timetable` WHERE `student_id`=(SELECT `student_id` FROM `student_accounts` WHERE `username`=?) AND `group`= (SELECT `group` FROM `student_timetable` WHERE `student_id` = (SELECT `student_id` FROM `student_accounts` WHERE `username`=?)");

if ($stmt !== FALSE)
{
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $inputUser, $inputUser);
}
else
{
    echo $mysqli->error; // optional - returns a string description of the last error
}
```

Have a look at the docs [PHP - mysqli::prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for further information.

Also, in case it helps, have a read up on JOINs, which may provide you with a better way of retrieving the records you want: [Understanding JOINs in MySQL and Other Relational Databases](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)